# Recover Bulk Deleted items in django framework

Tags: python, django, frameworks, delete-file, recover

Is it possible to recover multiple deleted files in one go using django framework. If so, what are the ways?

I tried latest file recovery, it worked. but not sure on multiple files recovery .

I am using IDE as pycharm and django admin view.

Comment: Recovering system deleted files has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.